# How to create a sub site template with multiple sub sites

Tags: 2010

I am creating a huge project site template in SharePoint 2010, which will contain multiple subsites and sub-subsites. However I have just found out that when saving it as a template the subsites are not saved with it.

I have done some research and I have found out that it can be done using Powershell.

I only have owner access. And I do not have access to SharePoint Central administration. But I hope IT will be able to help me, how ever I don't know how much expertise they have with SharePoint when it comes to coding and PowerShell.

Can anyone help me with a step by step guide to how to do this in Powershell?

I would greatly appreciate if any one can help me.

Thank you :-)

Comment: This has its permissive background. Your requirement is in fact saving a template of a `site collection`. If you only have owner access for a (root) site in your site collection, the permission's scope doesn't extend over the complete site collection. Therefore you'd at minimum need to have `site collection administrator` permission level. See [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85727/create-a-template-from-an-existing-site-collection-to-be-used-for-the-creation-o) related question as well.

Comment: The template is not meant to be saved as a site collection. We have a site collection which contains all project sites. Untill now the subsites for a project site have been added manually. But we would like to optimize this procedure by having the subsites added to the template.

Comment: Right, I understand your requirement. Have you seen the following question: [Trying to create a template with subsites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110254/trying-to-create-a-template-with-subsites)? That should be the step-by-step I'd give for your need.